# workflow logic problem on long text area

Tags: long-text-area, workflowrule

It keeps showing accounts with DMARC blank records.  I added 2 ISBLANK conditions to try to stop it but that doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing it has to be the way we combined the boolean logic.  Whats the proper way to say "all of X and any of Y"
Thanks!

Below is the workflow rule logic i am using

DMARC_Record__c is a data type of long text area.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(DMARC_Record__c),
    ISBLANK(DMARC_Record__c),
    ISBLANK(
        PRIORVALUE(DMARC_Record__c)
    ),
    PRIORVALUE(DMARC_Record__c) != DMARC_Record__c,
    NOT(
        CONTAINS(DMARC_Record__c, "xxx.com")
    ),
    OR(
        CONTAINS(
            PRIORVALUE(DMARC_Record__c), "xxx.com"
        ),
        CONTAINS(DMARC_Record__c, "yyy.com"),
        CONTAINS(DMARC_Record__c, "zzzz.com")
    )
)
```

Comment: I believe `Long Text Area` type fields are NOT evaluated in formulas. Here is possible workaround: http://linkingto.blogspot.com/2011/08/salesforce-long-text-area-and-formulas.html

Comment: Sorry if the question is silly, I am new to saesforce .I m little confused here I am using text area (long) after creating field it shows me long text area on the field. I have created DMARC_Record__c also with text area(long) only data type.

Comment: see [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhEAAS - 11,000+ votes